# Octopus deploy db connection error in linux container

Tags: sql-server, octopus

I created Octopus with docker-compose.yml and env file as below.
https://hub.docker.com/r/octopusdeploy/octopusdeploy

And built it, but I can't connect with database.

> Error: 18456, Severity:14, State: 8.
> Login failed for user 'sa'. Reason: Password did not match that for the login provided.

My database connection string in env file is like:

```
DB_CONNECTION_STRING=Server=db,1433;Database=OctopusDeploy;User=sa;Password=Password_01
```

Anyone can help me?

Comment: Does the password contain any shell characters? You may have to escape them.

Comment: my password does'nt contain any shell characters : <